# HashCat Separator Unmatched

Tags: encryption, hash, terminal, md5, hashcat

I am trying to get this hash:

```
633c097a37b26c0caad3b435b51404e
```

with the following command:

```
hashcat -a 0 -m 1800 -o final.txt hash.txt /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
```

But it gives me an error saying my separator is unmatched.

I'm new to this so I'm not exactly sure what that means or how I can fix it ...

Answer (score 1):

The hash you are trying with is of type **MD5**, so you have to specify the correct hash type for the hash mode flag `-m`, which is `0` for the MD5, so it should be `-m 0` instead of `-m 1800` which is used for **sha512crypt $6$, SHA512 (Unix) 2**.

Refer to this [link](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes) from the official documentation of **hashcat** which provides examples for all the has types.